# AltBeacon setRangeNotifier behaving Differently on Different Tablet Device

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I have 2 tablet one is Hewlett-Packard - HP Pro Slate 10 EE G1 (Version 5.0.2) and another one is TCL - 8079(Version 5.0.1) .and i am using ALTBeacon Library to Scan Beacons.

I have put all necessary code to bind the beaconmanager and all.but this is my `setRangeNotifier` method.

```
   public class MyApplication extends Application implements BeaconConsumer {


private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private String TAG = "MyApplication";


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);


    // Add parser for iBeacons;
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    // Detect the Eddystone main identifier (UID) frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));
    // Detect the Eddystone telemetry (TLM) frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"));
    // Detect the Eddystone URL frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v"));
    // Detect the Eddystone URL frame:
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    beaconManager.bind(this);


}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Log.e(TAG, "Servcie Connected..");


    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Servcie Scanning..");

            if (beacons.size() > 0)

            {

            Log.d(TAG, "Collected beacons size: " + beacons.size());

            }


    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}

}
```

Here is my code from Application Class where I perform this Scan.

Code is Working fine on Hewlett-Packard - HP Pro Slate 10 EE G1
but it is not working on TCL Tablet.TCl Connects beacon Service but not able to Scan device.

Is there any thing device bluetooth to do with Scanning.
is something i am missing therefore it is not working same on both device.

Same things happens like TCL in Asus Tablet too.

it gives me error

> "Cannot contact service to set scan periods"

Comment: Does the TCL Tablet support Bluetooth LE?  Can you detect beacons with an off the shelf app like Locate?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en

Comment: i don't know about TCL but ASUS are Nexus Tablet which supports BLE

Comment: Can you detect with the off the shelf beacon scanner Locate which uses this library?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate

Comment: yes i am able to scan with this app,and i found it is scanning the Device but it is very inconsistent in TCL - (Alcatel Onetouch, Pixi model) having bluetooth version 4.1 , it is not as smooth as HP Tablet having bluetooth version 4.0.why it is not same in all device..

Comment: The fact that you can detect with Locate, which uses the same library, suggests the problem in your app not detecting at all on the TCL tablet is a setup issue.  It may help to show more of your code that sets up tge library.

Comment: i just updated the code  i am scanning devices in Application class ,one more thing how to unbind the manager or stopRanging it from application class, i want to stop scanning while app is no more in foreground.

Comment: The library is designed to slow down scans when the app is in the background using the BackgroundPowerSaver.  If you want to completely stop scans when the app is in the background, you could simply set a really long between scan period like this:  mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(Long.MAX_VALUE);  This will only do a scan in the background every 292 million years.  I think that is probably close enough. :)